# Gnome 40 updated. not working

Tags: gnome, upgrade, manjaro

Today Manjaro Linux had a huge upgrade with Gnome 40. I upgraded my system and restarted it. but Gnome 40 is not enabled. I'm still seeing Gnome 38 in front of me.
here is the photo of my Gnome Version.

[image]

what's wrong here?

Comment: That screenshot clearly says "GNOME Version 40.0.0"

Comment: And application menu clearly says gnome 38. Gnome is updated to 40 but Gnome 38 is running

Comment: There's nothing on your screenshot that says version 38.   If there's some menu somewhere that you haven't actually shown that says "38" then it's probably a bug, a fixed string that someone forgot to edit.   The version of gnome running is clearly version 40.0.0

Comment: A huge bug by manjaro. Congrats!

Comment: It seems it was a partial update to Gnome 40. other packages will be upgraded soon. at least nothing is broken.

Comment: Dude, it's the apps have not been updated yet. You are definitely using GNOME 40

Comment: Could you try running "gnome-shell --version" in a terminal?

Comment: I switched to Kde and I'm safe for now. I tried Gnome for 3 times and every time it crashed. It was the fault of manjaro that released gnome partially on the stable channel.